# I can't send or receive email through my email server

Tags: email, postfix, ssl, dovecot

I am using SSL to encrypt my email server's communications. However, when I try to send messages to it or retrieve messages from it, it fails to do so.
Here is what it says in /var/log:

```
Oct 28 15:29:36 (server name) dovecot[602]: master: Error: service(imap-login): command startup failed, throttling for 16 secs
Oct 28 15:29:52 (server name) dovecot[14267]: imap-login: Fatal: Couldn't parse private ssl_key: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line: Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

And here is my postfix main.cf:

```
# Server information
mydomain = (domain name)
myorigin = (domain name)
  # Various other parameters use these two variables as default values.

# SMTP service
smtpd_tls_security_level    = may
smtpd_tls_cert_file         = /etc/letsencrypt/live/(domain name)/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file          = /etc/letsencrypt/live/(domain name)/privkey.pem
  # This allows STARTTLS to be used on all incoming SMTP connections.
  # Note that `postfix` must be added to the `ssl-cert` group to be able
  # to access files in /etc/ssl/private.

# Policies
mynetworks = [::1]/128, 127.0.0.0/8, [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104  
  # This lists the IP addresses that are considered "trusted" and can use  # this server to send mail to the outside (i.e. to other domains). By  # default, only "localhost" is allowed. From everyone else only mail to  # domains in $mydestination will be accepted.
  # This lists the IP addresses that are considered "trusted" and can use
  # this server to send mail to the outside (i.e. to other domains). By
  # default, only "localhost" is allowed. From everyone else only mail to
  # domains in $mydestination will be accepted.
mydestination = (domain name), localhost
  # List of domains to accept mail for, from any IP address.
# Delivery
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
  # This keeps system-wide aliases. It's good to set it explicitly because
  # the default value sometimes includes NIS, which doesn't make sense.
recipient_delimiter = +  
  # Tells postfix to split the local part of addresses at the first '+',  # so-called "plus-addressing": mail sent to diti+foo@ will be delivered  # to the diti@ mailbox.
  # Tells postfix to split the local part of addresses at the first '+',
  # so-called "plus-addressing": mail sent to diti+foo@ will be delivered
  # to the diti@ mailbox.
mynetworks_style = subnet
home_mailbox = Mail/
# Authentication
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
```

And my master.cf:

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       y       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

And here is my dovecot config:

```
##
## Authentication processes
##

# Disable LOGIN command and all other plaintext authentications unless
# SSL/TLS is used (LOGINDISABLED capability). Note that if the remote IP
# matches the local IP (ie. you're connecting from the same computer), the
# connection is considered secure and plaintext authentication is allowed.
# See also ssl=required setting.
disable_plaintext_auth = yes

# Authentication cache size (e.g. 10M). 0 means it's disabled. Note that
# bsdauth, PAM and vpopmail require cache_key to be set for caching to be used.
#auth_cache_size = 0
# Time to live for cached data. After TTL expires the cached record is no
# longer used, *except* if the main database lookup returns internal failure.
# We also try to handle password changes automatically: If user's previous
# authentication was successful, but this one wasn't, the cache isn't used.
# For now this works only with plaintext authentication.
#auth_cache_ttl = 1 hour
# TTL for negative hits (user not found, password mismatch).
# 0 disables caching them completely.
#auth_cache_negative_ttl = 1 hour

# Space separated list of realms for SASL authentication mechanisms that need
# them. You can leave it empty if you don't want to support multiple realms.
# Many clients simply use the first one listed here, so keep the default realm
# first.
#auth_realms =

# Default realm/domain to use if none was specified. This is used for both
# SASL realms and appending @domain to username in plaintext logins.
#auth_default_realm = 

# List of allowed characters in username. If the user-given username contains
# a character not listed in here, the login automatically fails. This is just
# an extra check to make sure user can't exploit any potential quote escaping
# vulnerabilities with SQL/LDAP databases. If you want to allow all characters,
# set this value to empty.
#auth_username_chars = abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890.-_@

# Username character translations before it's looked up from databases. The
# value contains series of from -> to characters. For example "#@/@" means
# that '#' and '/' characters are translated to '@'.
#auth_username_translation =

# Username formatting before it's looked up from databases. You can use
# the standard variables here, eg. %Lu would lowercase the username, %n would
# drop away the domain if it was given, or "%n-AT-%d" would change the '@' into
# "-AT-". This translation is done after auth_username_translation changes.
#auth_username_format = %Lu

# If you want to allow master users to log in by specifying the master
# username within the normal username string (ie. not using SASL mechanism's
# support for it), you can specify the separator character here. The format
# is then <username><separator><master username>. UW-IMAP uses "*" as the
# separator, so that could be a good choice.
#auth_master_user_separator =

# Username to use for users logging in with ANONYMOUS SASL mechanism
#auth_anonymous_username = anonymous

# Maximum number of dovecot-auth worker processes. They're used to execute
# blocking passdb and userdb queries (eg. MySQL and PAM). They're
# automatically created and destroyed as needed.
#auth_worker_max_count = 30

# Host name to use in GSSAPI principal names. The default is to use the
# name returned by gethostname(). Use "$ALL" (with quotes) to allow all keytab
# entries.
#auth_gssapi_hostname =

# Kerberos keytab to use for the GSSAPI mechanism. Will use the system
# default (usually /etc/krb5.keytab) if not specified. You may need to change
# the auth service to run as root to be able to read this file.
#auth_krb5_keytab = 

# Do NTLM and GSS-SPNEGO authentication using Samba's winbind daemon and
# ntlm_auth helper. <doc/wiki/Authentication/Mechanisms/Winbind.txt>
#auth_use_winbind = no

# Path for Samba's ntlm_auth helper binary.
#auth_winbind_helper_path = /usr/bin/ntlm_auth

# Time to delay before replying to failed authentications.
#auth_failure_delay = 2 secs

# Require a valid SSL client certificate or the authentication fails.
#auth_ssl_require_client_cert = no

# Take the username from client's SSL certificate, using 
# X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID() which returns the subject's DN's
# CommonName. 
#auth_ssl_username_from_cert = no

# Space separated list of wanted authentication mechanisms:
#   plain login digest-md5 cram-md5 ntlm rpa apop anonymous gssapi otp skey
#   gss-spnego
# NOTE: See also disable_plaintext_auth setting.
auth_mechanisms = apop

##
## Password and user databases
##

passdb {
  driver = pam
  args = %s
}

# Password database is used to verify user's password (and nothing more).
# You can have multiple passdbs and userdbs. This is useful if you want to
# allow both system users (/etc/passwd) and virtual users to login without
# duplicating the system users into virtual database.
#
# <doc/wiki/PasswordDatabase.txt>
#
# User database specifies where mails are located and what user/group IDs
# own them. For single-UID configuration use "static" userdb.
#
# <doc/wiki/UserDatabase.txt>

#!include auth-deny.conf.ext
#!include auth-master.conf.ext

!include auth-system.conf.ext
#!include auth-sql.conf.ext
#!include auth-ldap.conf.ext
#!include auth-passwdfile.conf.ext
#!include auth-checkpassword.conf.ext
#!include auth-vpopmail.conf.ext
#!include auth-static.conf.ext
```

Here is the output of `doveconf -n`:

```
# 2.2.27 (c0f36b0): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.4.16 (fed8554)
# OS: Linux 4.9.0-4-686-pae i686 Debian 9.2 
auth_mechanisms = login
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  args = %s
  driver = pam
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = " imap"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3s {
    port = 995
    ssl = yes
  }
}
ssl_cert = /etc/letsencrypt/live/(domain name)/fullchain.pem
ssl_key =  # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? all of the required ports are open. I am using Thunderbird as an email client.

Comment: Please provide the output of `doveconf -n`, which prints Dovecot's current configuration.

Answer (score 3):

The error message at the top of the question tells you exactly what the problem is, and where to look for it:

> ```
> Oct 28 15:29:52 (server name) dovecot[14267]: imap-login: Fatal: Couldn't parse private ssl_key
> error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line: Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
> ```

The problem you have listed is nothing to do with Postfix; it's reported by the IMAP Login component for Dovecot. It tells you that the private SSL key you have defined is not a valid file. It's supposed to begin with `ANY PRIVATE KEY` but it doesn't.

I'd point out the appropriate line in your Dovecot configuration, but you haven't included that component in your question.

None of this applies to a Postfix problem that doesn't allow you to send or receive email. If that is the problem you want addressing you should include relevant error messages and log files from Postfix. Not from Dovecot.

Comment: I think I found the problem, I accidentally mixed up the SSL cert and private key lines. Is there any chance that I could have leaked the private key, and if so, I should regenerate it, right?

Comment: @Haxalicious no it's not been leaked, because Dovecot couldn't even read it (wrong format). But if you'd be happier regenerating it, go right ahead; there's no harm in doing so.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a number of questions regarding IMAP/SMTP TLS certs and communication.  I remember struggling to understand this myself.  I made diagram of the pathway and which certs are used where...

I think this is correct, at least my servers work as expected.  So, if it's not correct, then it's at least somewhat correct.  The main point is that there are two certs, not one.  I use Courier, so adjust the variables appropriately.

```
                 .----------------------------.
                 | IMAP                       |
                 | x509 Cert                  |
        .------->|                            |----------.
        |        | TLS_CERTFILE=some_cert.pem |          |
        |        | TLS_DHPARAMS=dhparms.pem   |          |
        |        '----------------------------'          |
        |                                                |
        |                                                |
        |                                                |
        |  TLS Provided by                               |
        |  IMAP connection                               |
        |                                                v
        |                                .------------------------------.
        |                                | SMTP                         |
        |                                | x509 Cert                    |
 .-------------.                         |                              |
 | IMAP Client |                         | smtpd_tls_security_level=may |
 '-------------'                         | smtpd_tls_cert_file          |
                                         | smtpd_tls_key_file           |
                                         |                              |
                                         '------------------------------'
                                                         |
                                                         |
                              TLS Provided by            |
                              SMTP connection            |
                              (may = cert not required)  |
                                                         |
                                                         |
                                                         v
                                                 .---------------.
                                                 | Receiver SMTP |
                                                 '---------------'
```